# Can Anaconda and a more recent version of Python coexist in Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am taking a beginner course in Python so I downloaded and installed Anaconda on a
Windows 10 OS. It is possible to install the last version of Python, say 3.9.x or 3.10 to be run on VSCode. How do I manage to avoid conflicts between them. Can anyone tell how should I do because I have to use that text editor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, they can coexist just fine. You simply set the interpreter/environment you wish to use in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but Anaconda includes an environment management tool, Conda, and so it would be more idiomatic to use that to create a new environment, rather than installing a native, system- or user-level Python interpreter. If you are using Anaconda, then from Anaconda Command Prompt try

```bash
conda create -n py39 python=3.9
```

or

```bash
conda create -n py310 python=3.10
```

Note the argument used in the `-n` (or `--name`) is arbitrary - feel free to name environments as you'd like.